# How to retrieve all child elements for all parent elements from xml in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

```
<people>
<parent>
  <parent-name> joel </parent-name>
  <child> john </child>
  <child> sara </child>
  <child> ram </child>
</parent>

<parent>
  <parent-name> sam </parent-name>
  <child> david </child>
  <child> george </child>
  <child> wilson </child>
</parent>
</people>
```

the desired output is:

```
parent  |  child
--------|---------
joel    |  john
joel    |  sara
joel    |  ram
sam     |  david
sam     |  george
sam     |  wilson
```

I tried the following sql query to retrieve all child element for all parent, only I can get first child element

```
select a.b.value('parent-name[1]','varchar(50)') as parent
      , a.b.value('child[1]' ,'varchar(50)') as child
from @myxml.nodes('people/parent')a(b)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to iterate the children, then go up one level and get the parent name.

```
select a.b.value('(../parent-name)[1]','varchar(50)') as parent
  , a.b.value('(.)[1]' ,'varchar(50)') as child
from @myxml.nodes('people/parent/child')a(b)
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `CROSS APPLY` and `.nodes()` on the `<child>` nodes of each parent node:

```
SELECT
    a.b.value('(parent-name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as parent, 
    XChild.value('.' ,'varchar(50)') as child
FROM
    @myxml.nodes('people/parent') AS a(b)
CROSS APPLY
    b.nodes('child') AS XTbl(XChild)
```

This will return all parents with all their children.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select 
tbl.col.value('parent::*/@parent-name', 'varchar(50)') AS ParentName,
tbl.col.value('@child', 'varchar(50)') AS ChildName
from @x.nodes('/people/parent/child') as tbl(col);
```